# Python negative exponent vs. division

Tags: python, floating-point

In Python, should I use negative exponents or division? Example:

```
>>> num = 2.0**-1
```

or

```
>>> num = 1/2.0
```

I ran a little test, and it looks like the difference comes down to BINARY_POWER vs. BINARY_DIVIDE:

```
import dis

def exp_test(x):
    return x**-1

def div_test(x):
    return 1/x

print "Exp Test:"
dis.dis(exp_test)
print "Div Test:"
dis.dis(div_test)
```

Output:

```
Exp Test:
2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
            3 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
            6 BINARY_POWER        
            7 RETURN_VALUE 
Div Test:
2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
            3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
            6 BINARY_DIVIDE       
            7 RETURN_VALUE
```

I am only thinking about floating-point values here. I imagine that I only need to worry about the usual differences that arise in floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: What are you concerned about? Safety? Performance? Precision?

Comment: @Cyber More concerned with safety and precision than performance or speed.

Comment: What range of input values do you expect to use this for?  Only `1/2`?

Comment: @BrianCain Floating-point values in the denominator: 1/x or x^(-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're computing the reciprocal of a Python `float` `x`, I can't think of any reason to prefer `x**-1.0` to `1.0/x`. Subjectively, I find the latter easier to read.  Objectively, it's likely to be both faster (because it's wrapping a single simple CPU instruction rather than a call to the C library's pow function) and more accurate (for pretty much the same reason).

Note that I'm deliberately using `1.0` instead of `1` in both expressions, both because that avoids an extra int-to-float conversion in the case that `x` is a float, and because it'll guarantee that I get a proper float division instead of a floor division on Python 2.7 in the case that `x` happens to be an int.

To back up the "faster" claim, here are some timings on my machine, including variants with both `1` and `1.0`.  This is under Python 2.7, but results are similar under Python 3.4.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('x**-1', 'x=12.34')
0.08957314491271973
>>> timeit.timeit('x**-1.0', 'x=12.34')
0.08102011680603027
>>> timeit.timeit('1/x', 'x=12.34')
0.06166410446166992
>>> timeit.timeit('1.0/x', 'x=12.34')
0.04489898681640625
```

There's a reasonably clear advantage to the division form here, and a noticeable speedup from using `1.0` instead of `1`.  Your results may vary.

Note: don't fall into the trap of timing expressions like `2**-1` or `1.0/2.0` directly.  Those expressions may be optimised by Python's peephole optimiser to a constant at compile time, so that all you end up timing is the time to retrieve the constant `0.5`.  You can see this using the `dis` module from the standard library:

```
>>> def half_via_pow(): return 2.0**-1.0
... 
>>> def half_via_div(): return 1.0/2.0
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(half_via_pow)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (0.5)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(half_via_div)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1.0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2.0)
              6 BINARY_DIVIDE       
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

The above shows that on Python 2.7, the computation `2.0**-1.0` is optimised to a constant, while the division `1.0/2.0` is not.  In Python 3.4, both are optimised to a constant.  I suspect that the Python 2.7 peephole optimizer avoids optimising divisions so that it doesn't have to worry about the case where it needs to raise `ZeroDivisionError`.  Either way, timing `2.0**-1.0` against `1.0/2.0` doesn't give an accurate reflection of the speed of `1.0/x` versus `x**-1.0`.  Time `1.0/x` against `x**-1.0` instead, and supply a value for `x` in the setup step.

For the "more accurate" claim:  `1.0/x` will resolve to a single machine instruction, which is almost certainly going to give you correctly-rounded results.  In contrast, library implementations of `pow` are notoriously bad, and will very often give results that aren't correctly rounded.  Even in the best case that your math library's `pow` operation *is* correctly rounded, it's still not going to be more accurate than the division result.

As a test, I tried the following loop, comparing `1.0 / x` with `x ** -1.0` for random `x` values:

```
>>> import random
>>> while True:
...     x = random.random()
...     print(repr(x))
...     assert 1.0/x == x**-1.0
```

Sure enough, after about 200 iterations, I get this:

```
<around 200 lines of output omitted>
0.16606458447273365
0.6466363135038045
0.8650060330740814
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Taking a look at the that last `x` value, I get:

```
>>> x = 0.8650060330740814
>>> 1.0 / x
1.1560613010364489
>>> x ** -1.0
1.1560613010364487
```

As a crude check that it's the result of `1.0 / x` that's correctly rounded here, we can convert the float to `Fraction` (which does an exact conversion), take the reciprocal as a `Fraction`, and then convert back to `float`.  The `Fraction` to `float` conversion is correctly-rounded, and doesn't use floating-point arithmetic to compute the result, so we're not depending on the accuracy of floating-point division in this check.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> float(1 / Fraction(x))
1.1560613010364489
```

(The exact reciprocal of `x`, computed to 25 significant digits, is `1.156061301036448774438694`.  The value we get back from `1.0 / x`, computed to the same precision, is `1.156061301036448885071195`, while the value from `x ** -1.0` is `1.156061301036448663026590`, so `1.0 / x` is only just closer to the true value than `x ** -1.0`, but it is closer.)

And finally, and to my mind most importantly, the `1.0 / x` is easier to read and requires less mental effort to parse.

All in all, there's very little reason to prefer the `**` form.

Comment: Thanks! I saw some code this morning with the exponent form and I thought it looked _strange_ , but I didn't have a practical reason for not using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering time, it seems to be Python version dependent (at least).

**Python 2.7**

```
import timeit

>>> timeit.timeit('2.0**-1')
0.017730650260812

>>> timeit.timeit('1/2.0')
0.07249812618659046
```

**Python 3.4**

```
import timeit

>>> timeit.timeit('2.0**-1')
0.03804316809533148

>>> timeit.timeit('1/2.0')
0.01787598969687565
```

Comment: Don't you mean that it is half as fast?  Seems like bigger times would mean slower ;-)

Comment: your timings seem a lot different to what I get

Comment: @mgilson I... uh... I don't know I'm an engineer not a tech writer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham His are different from mine as well. On my setup (Python 3.4, i7-3770) the times are very close, with the negative exponentiation being very slightly faster.

Comment: @RogerFan on python 3 the times are identical almost but on python 2 exponentiation is almost three times as fast as division on my computer

Comment: The OP is using python 2

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Using iPython Timeit Magic I get that exponentiation is faster: `%timeit 2.0**-1  100000000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ns per loop` versus `%timeit 1/2.0  10000000 loops, best of 3: 48.2 ns per loop`

Comment: @RogerFan, yes I get similar times

Comment: You need to take into account the peephole optimizer in these timings.  In Python 2.7, the expression `2.0**-1` is optimized to the constant `0.5` at compilation time, while `1/2.0` is not.  In Python 3.4, both expressions are optimized away at compile time. For better timings, compare `x**-1` and `1/x` and use a setup string of `x = 2.0`.